# Exception when creating Spring Context with JMS Service references

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, camel-jms

We have a Swing UI client which uses an Appclient which sets up a Spring framework context with CAMEL beans for talking to remote services in an OSGi server via JMS.

Here's an example of one of the service references:

```
<bean id="computerDataManager" class="org.apache.camel.spring.remoting.CamelProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="jms:queue:computerDataManager"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="xxxx.core.api.ComputerDataInterface"/>
</bean>
```

Recently we added 'camel-http' features to the OSGi (Karaf) server to allow the use of HTTP URI endpoints.

This inclusion on the server has started creating a warning when the client starts with the following Stacktrace:

```
[AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO uniworks.resources.standardclasses.various.SingletonDialogEvent - Got a Dialog Event,  event = O
[AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO uniworks.resources.standardclasses.various.SingletonDialogEvent - Firing an Event with Dialog event - O
[Thread-0] WARN org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Ignoring converter type: org.apache.camel.component.http.RequestEntityConverter as a dependent class could not be found: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader.loadConverterMethods(AnnotationTypeConverterLoader.java:262)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader.load(AnnotationTypeConverterLoader.java:130)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.loadTypeConverters(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:544)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter.doStart(DefaultTypeConverter.java:53)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:2885)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1106)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1067)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1063)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getTypeConverter(DefaultCamelContext.java:1993)
        at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.setProperties(EndpointHelper.java:252)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:263)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent.createEndpoint(JmsComponent.java:554)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:114)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:558)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.remoting.CamelProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CamelProxyFactoryBean.java:65)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1371)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:751)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:526)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1180)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.getBeanForType(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.java:153)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:256)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1123)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelBeanPostProcessor$1.getOrLookupCamelContext(CamelBeanPostProcessor.java:69)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor.java:87)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(CamelBeanPostProcessor.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1507)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1371)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:751)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:526)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:906)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:864)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:503)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

This appears to indicate that when our existing JMS endpoints are being created, it is somehow finding a reference to the 'RequestEntity' class. There is no reference to this class in any of our code, so we're not sure why this warning has started appearing.

Is there any way we can get more information about which bean it is trying to instantiate?

Comment: Can you also include the dependency of your project?

Comment: @samabcde  Our Swing UI is a (very) rich client with 70+ dependencies in the project's POM. About half of those are third-party libraries, including Spring and Camel. Not sure how much information it is going to add to the question to list all of those dependencies. I will say that the list of dependencies has not changed recently, but, the 'camel-http' bundle was added as a dependency to one of our Karaf server bundles (which is not a dependency of UI)

Comment: Have you tried initializing your application in debug mode? It seems that some component needs to instantiate `RequestEntity` to work properly but can't find it. So, my guess is your app lacks some dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually tracked it down to a third-hand dependency of the Karaf bundle that had the 'camel-http' added to it.

We didn't have the 'interface' classes for the services in a separate bundle. Once we separated them out and only included that 'api' bundle with the interfaces, the error went away.